# Best Way to Create Table of Aggregate Values SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Short question:**

Is there a simple way to get tables of aggregate values to display in neat rows and columns in raw sql? Ex. Total sales over select years, where the column names are the years and the row cells are aggregate totals.

```
     2005    2006    2007
--------------------------
Gary $500    $1000  $2000
Joe  $500    $500   $500
```

**Context:**

I have a set of data that I am constantly reporting out of. My work has BI tools, and for some kinds of reporting they are very useful, but they are also somewhat clunky and rather inflexible. Another problem with BI tools is that it can be very difficult to get a very polished looking, custom formatted report, so what I end up doing a lot is writing a report, getting the output, moving it into the Microsoft office suite and then doing more formatting there. Whenever possible I prefer to run raw sql because it is so much easier to document, I can manually copy and paste values into excel, and it usually takes me less time than writing a BI report.

On occasion I have to create tables of aggregate data, where, for purely cosmetic reasons, the columns and rows are only loosely related to one another. Often I have to do something fairly complex with the data in order to get all the pieces of information together. The code I end up writing in SQL server is very verbose, clunky, and inefficient, but works:

1. I create a table variable
2. I write a statement that selects one row of the table using a series of sum/case statement
3. I insert each select statement one by one into the temporary table and display the table.

Example:

```
DECLARE @Temp AS TABLE(
 ord int --I can use an ORDER BY clause against this to make sure the rows display in the correct order
,"2004-2005" INT
,"2005-2006" INT
,"2006-2007" INT
,"2007-2008" INT
,"2008-2009" INT
,"2009-2010" INT
,"2010-2011" INT
,"2011-2012" INT
,"2012-2013" INT
,"2013-2014" INT
)

INSERT INTO @Temp
Select
1
,SUM(CASE WHEN something = 'blah' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2004-2005'
--similar code here
WHERE whatever = something

Select * FROM @temp ORDER BY ord
```

So my question is, within SQL, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Pivot for Multiple Metrics by Year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29256175/sql-pivot-for-multiple-metrics-by-year)

Answer (score 0):

To simplify, you could try:

```
SELECT 1
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN something = 'blah' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2004-2005'
       --similar code here
INTO #temp
FROM YourTable
WHERE whatever = something 


SELECT * FROM #temp
```

This way your temp table will last as long as your current session.